# Nested rows with bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, gridview, programación-móvil

Necesito crear una rejilla, como lo muestra la siguiente imagen, estoy utilizando **bootstrap 3** 
Ejemplo: [image: La imagen muestra un ejemplo de la rejilla]

Gracias!!

Comment: El idioma oficial de SO es en español, traduce tu pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: Gracias, he cambiado el idioma

Comment: Saludos Dann, por curiosidad ¿Qué has intentado? Si la respuesta es nada, te invito a que intentes algo, de tal manera motivas a los integrantes de SOes a que respondan tu pregunta :D buenas vibras lml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar el siguiente código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      Contenido 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              Contenido 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Btn ok</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <button class="btn btn-default">Btn cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido, solamente que estoy usando Bootstrap 3, pero funciono correctamente.

Comment: Por nada, creo que lo único que no funciona son las clases col-6 sin especificar la resolución que fue una mejora agregada en la nueva versión para esos casos vas a tener que especificar como quieres que se comporte la columna correspondiente para las resoluciones lg md sm y xs . Saludos! y Buenos códigos!

Comment: Es correcto, de nuevo muchas gracias!